# Unable to change the value of primary key in Realm Android

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I'm trying to change the current value of primary key to another. Like this.

```
realm?.executeTransactionAsync ({ realm ->
    val teamRealmObj = realm?.where(Team::class.java)?.equalTo("name", oldTeamName)?.findFirst()
        teamRealmObj?.name = newTeamName
    })
```

Here name attribute is a primary key.

I'm getting this error.

> Failed Primary key field 'name' cannot be changed after the object was created.

How can I achieve this? Do I have to make a copy(only different name attribute) and delete the old one? This will cause headache in one to many or many to many relations as the new object must be replaced every where in the database.

Need a better way to do this. Thank you if anybody can help me to figure this out.

Comment: `Do I have to make an exact copy and delete the old one?` yes, although `copyFromRealm()` can help

Comment: No. My need is to just change name attribute of the existing RealmObject in database.

Comment: You cannot modify the value of a primary key of a managed object after it has been created

Comment: Is it completely impossible in Realm?

Comment: See https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys **Once an object with a primary key is added to a Realm, the primary key cannot be changed.**

Comment: Is there any alternative to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, creating a copy using `copyFromRealm()`, modifying the primary key, inserting the new object, and deleting the old one. Deletion of the object invalidates object links, so you'll need to rebuild links for relations. Another option is to make it not be a primary key using a migration, but then you'll need to use `copyToRealm()`/`insert()` instead, and you'd need to do the updates manually, and ensure you are not making duplicates.

Comment: This is going to be messy in creating links again. Thank you for the time. Really helpful

Comment: Personally, I recommend not using a field as primary key if you expect to change it later.

Comment: I got it solved. Answered my own question. :-)

Answer (score 5):

This piece of code fixed my issue.

```
realm?.executeTransactionAsync ({ realm ->
        val teamRealmObj = realm.where(Team::class.java)?.equalTo("name", oldTeamName)?.findFirst()
        val newTeamObj = realm.copyFromRealm(teamRealmObj)
        newTeamObj?.name = newTeamName
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newTeamObj)
        teamRealmObj?.deleteFromRealm()
    }
```

There is no need to recreate the links.

```
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newTeamObj)
```

This line is automatically doing this.

Comment: Hopefully your linked objects also have primary key?